# (Видео стрим с вебки на сервер) Как склеивать Видео Блоб элементы на лету

Tags: javascript, потоки-данных, mediarecorder

> Хочу сказать сразу, не взял WebRTC, потому, как я понял, что они
>   расчитана на п2п, и если сделать свой велосипед или заюзать чей то, то
>   он все равно юзает п2п и объеденяет всех, в итоге для каждого юзера
>   нужен хороший интернет что бы выдерживать такой поток (когда в комнате
>   будет 30 человек, каждый должен будет отослать остальным 29 свое видео
>   и так же принимать, от тех же 29, видео)

Хочу сделать видео комнату через сервер (ноджс\голенг). С отправкой на сервер и отправки с сервера остальным юзерам вроде не проблема.
Не могу понять как на фронте качественно принимать видео фрагменты и подставлять в видео тег. И что бы видео красиво шло безпрерывно в лайв режиме.

К примеру, 1 что в голову пришло, если заюзать такой код (пока без серверной части) то на "швах" видны блики.

```
let video = document.querySelector("video");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then( stream => {

      let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.start();

      setInterval( () => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.start();
      },200);

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
        let blob = new Blob([e.data], {type: "video/webm"});
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      };

    })
    .catch( e => { console.log("Something went wrong!", e) });
}
```

Подскажите как записывать фрагменты по 200-500мс, отправлять на сервер и потом качественно склеивать на клиентской части.

Или же возможен какой то прямой стриминг, как в примере с WebRTC, или еще что то, а то в этом направлении первый раз.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start - метод start принимает длину чанков в миллисекундах

Comment: Как мне это должно помочь? я все так же не могу склеить без швов.

Comment: 1) Как минимум, Вы не будете "лепить" костыли, а будете использовать нативыне методы. 2) У нас нет возможности увидеть Ваши швы, т.к. Вы не предоставили весь, необходимый для этого, код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f69dohug Нужна подключенная вебка.

Comment: Нашел похоже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333767/html5-video-streaming-video-with-blob-urls но оно не работает, бьет ошибку `Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`

Comment: Вы,  случайно, не в Safari iOS это тестите?  в нем, вроде как не поддерживается

Comment: в хроме (виндовс)
блин похоже придется на WebRTC делать если такая лажа :)

Comment: этот пример видели? https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferAll.html

Comment: так это целый файл скачивается и воспроизводиться.
А мне с вебки нужно в режиме онлайн гонять

Comment: Может я не правильно фрагменты обрабатываю, хотя разное перепробовал, все что нашел в интернете. Мне бы похожую рабочую систему найти

Comment: Наткнулся на интересный репозиторий и вспомнил про Ваш вопрос: https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на правильный ответ, но сдается мне, что Вы не правильно иммитируете задачу.
В Вашем варианте, `video` воспроизводит каждый `chunk` создаваемый `MediaRecorder` по отдельности. Отсюда и мигание. Видеоплеер каждый раз останавливается, а потом стартует заново. Если Вы начнете воспроизводить непосредственно `stream`, то все воспроизводится как ожидается. Соответственно, этот `stream` Вам необходимо реализовать через сервер

```
let video = document.querySelector("video");
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then( stream => {

  let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  mediaRecorder.start(500);
    video.srcObject = stream;
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
    console.log(e)
  }

}).catch( e => {});
```

Comment: я знаю что не правильно, я это и отписывал в первом посте.
И спросил совета, как лепить, когда каждые 200-500мс сервер будет присылать куски стрима